# Casting variable

Tags: php, variables

Does casting a variable to (string) or (int) change the variable for only that instance for which the (string) or (int) cast is used or does this casting 'stay' with the variable afterwards?

Comment: It should stay till the end of the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = "1";
$b= (int)$a;
if((int)$a===1){
echo "Yes its casted and 1"; // printed
}
if($b===1){
echo "Yes  b is 1"; //printed
}
if($a===1){
echo "Sorry this not casted"; //not printed
}
```

If you cast the variable and store it in another variable it will remain till end other wise you can just cast for 1 process;